# Difficulty in understanding C-style typecasting and dynamic cast

Tags: c++, casting

I have been trying to understand type casting in C++. In the following code class B is child class of class A and both share polymorphic relationship.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A{
    int a;
    public:
        virtual void sayhello() {cout<<"Hello from A"<<endl;}
};
class B:public A{
    int b;
    public:
        void sayhello(){cout<<"Hello from B"<<endl;}
        void another_func(){cout<<"Hello from B::another_func"<<endl;}
};
int main() {

    A *temp1 = new A;
    //Statement 1
    B *b =(B*) temp1;

    //Statement 2
    //B* b = dynamic_cast<B*>(temp1);


    b->another_func();

    delete temp1;
    return 0;
}
```

OUtput of above program -

```
Hello from B::another_func
```

I have difficultly in understanding the following issues -
1) For statement 1 How can we cast a parent object to child object.Logically this should be incorrect as now we have widened the capabilities of this object(the same object can now access the child class function another_func).

**A similar code in Java produces an error-**

**"incompatible types: A cannot be converted to B

        B b = (A)temp;"**

Now if we comment statement 1 & uncomment statement 2 a similar thing happens for statement 2.
So, Why does C++ allows this?
2) Now if we remove sayhello() function from both classes such that they do not have a polymorphic relationship the statement 2 that is dynamic_cast  no longer works(as we know dynamic_cast can downcast polymorphic classes) but c-style cast that is statement 1 still produces the same output.
So we can say that c-style cast is not based on polymorphic relationship between classes. 
What are the parameters based on which c-style cast happens?

Comment: Your program invokes undefined behavior. Pretty much anything can happen; the standard hyperbole is that [the computer is allowed to make demons fly out your nose](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you toggle the comments so that the C-style cast is commented, and the `dynamic_cast` is uncommented. Furthermore, modify the code so it is:

```
B* b = dynamic_cast<B*>(temp1);
if(b == nullptr)
    cout << "not really a B" << endl;
else
    b->another_func();
```

Then when running the code, it prints out "not really a B".

If you look at [what `dynamic_cast` does](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast)

> If the cast is successful, dynamic_cast returns a value of type new_type. If the cast fails and new_type is a pointer type, it returns a null pointer of that type.

So your version using `dynamic_cast` was undefined behavior, since you dereferenced the pointer without checking whether the cast failed.

---

Now to all the different versions using the C-Style cast. [The rules](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast) are:

> When the C-style cast expression is encountered, the compiler attempts to interpret it as the following cast expressions, in this order:
>
> a) const_cast(expression);
>
> b) static_cast(expression), with extensions: pointer or reference to a derived class is additionally allowed to be cast to pointer or reference to unambiguous base class (and vice versa) even if the base class is inaccessible (that is, this cast ignores the private inheritance specifier). Same applies to casting pointer to member to pointer to member of unambigous non-virtual base;
>
> c) static_cast (with extensions) followed by const_cast;
>
> d) reinterpret_cast(expression);
>
> e) reinterpret_cast followed by const_cast.
>   The first choice that satisfies the requirements of the respective cast operator is selected, even if it cannot be compiled (see example). If the cast can be interpreted in more than one way as static_cast followed by a const_cast, it cannot be compiled.

According to these rules, your C-style cast is equivalent to

```
B *b = static_cast<B *>(temp1);
```

Since `temp1` actually points to an `A` object, dereferencing the result is undefined behavior as well (but for a different reason).

---

Some general points:

1. C++ casts are a fine-grained version of C-style casts. If you must cast, prefer them. You can convey to the compiler what aspect you're casting.
2. You probably should try to avoid casting in any case. If you *do* use `dynamic_cast`, check the result.

Comment: The `static_cast` does not give undefined behaviour.   Attempting to dereference `b` does.   The only form of `static_cast` which gives undefined behaviour (and only proposed in C++17) is converting a out-of-range numeric type to an enum type.

Comment: @Peter OMG, that was really horrible phrasing on my part. Many thanks! Your comment was very helpful.

Comment: @Peter: Holy crap! Can you provide a link to that proposal? EDIT: [Found it.](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1766)

Answer (score 1):

The C-style cast is unchecked. In your case it simply tells the compiler to consider the pointer `temp1` to be of type `B`. With your code this is a lie and using this pointer in any form will result in undefined behavior. One outcome of undefined behavior is that it does what you happen to somehow expect. C-style casts are "inherited" from C and are needed to get a lot of C code to compile with C++.

Sometimes C-style casts do the Right Thing but there are multiple different conversions they can perform and it is often not immediately clear which operation they do: a cast `(T)x` can be equivalent to a `reinterpret_cast<T>(x)`, a `static_cast<T>(x)`, a `const_cast<T>(x)`, or a combination thereof. Generally only combinations of `static_cast<T>(x)` and `const_cast<T>(x)` result in a well-defined result and even then there are preconditions which are not checked. For example, casting a pointer `p` to a base `B` to a pointer of a derived `D` using `static_cast<D*>(p)` is only defined if `p` was produced from a pointer `D` by directly converting the `D` pointer to a `B` pointer.